# Meaning of template<auto = {}>

Tags: c++, templates, auto

What type and default value does the single template parameter have in the following code?

```
template<auto = {}>
int getInt();
```

Clang with `-Xclang -ast-dump` only says:

```
| |-NonTypeTemplateParmDecl 0xcb77130 <line:1:10, col:18> col:15 'auto' depth 0 index 0
| | `-TemplateArgument expr
| |   `-InitListExpr 0xcb77050 <col:17, col:18> 'void'
```

Comment: AFAIK nothing.  `{}` has no type.

Comment: Can't compile: `error: expected expression`

Comment: But in Compiler Explorer it does compile, both with Clang and GCC: https://godbolt.org/z/nWebjs79h.

Comment: it doesnt have a type: https://godbolt.org/z/9qWWWdWaa

Comment: It's being parsed, but it hasn't been instantiated.  Which doesn't say much for "does compile", other than it has parseable syntax.

Comment: It's parsed only in Clang 18. I can't get it parsed in GCC.

Comment: @273K no problem here https://godbolt.org/z/aMY7dea7h

Comment: Starting with some later C++ version (i.e. not in C++11), a "template non-type parameter" can be "auto", meaning it's deduced from whatever is supplied when the template is used. However, at this stage, I can't wrap my head around what the initializer might be good for...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this template:

```cpp
template<int = "">
int getInt();
```

It compiles successfully, but the default value can't actually be used:

```cpp
int main() {
    getInt();
}
```

```cpp
<source>:5:5: error: no matching function for call to 'getInt'
    5 |     getInt();
      |     ^~~~~~
<source>:2:5: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure: value of type 'const char[1]' is not implicitly convertible to 'int'
    1 | template<int = "">
      |                ~~
    2 | int getInt();
      |     ^
```

You have to explicitly call it with a value, like `getInt<0>();`

It's the same with `template<auto = {}>`: A default value is provided, but the type can't be deduced from the initializer, so `getInt()` can't call that function template. You can only ever use `getInt<(initializer)>{}`.

---

If you're wondering what `auto` means, it's a placeholder type. It's not deduced from the default, it's deduced from the initializer in the call (which may be the default if nothing is provided or otherwise deduced).

So this is perfectly valid:

```cpp
template<auto = 0>
int getInt();

char x;
int main() {
    getInt();  // Type of the first NTTP is `int`, deduced from `0`.
    getInt<&x>();  // Type of the first NTTP is `char*`, deduced from `&x`. Default is not used.
}
```